# Can I use C++14 in a library meant for C++11 client applications?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

If I'm building a library where I assume that some "clients" of the library may only be using C++11, can I compile the library itself using C++14 for its internals? Are there API/ABI/link compatibility issues versus C++11? Is it safe to implement and build the library with C++14 as long as I avoid certain new features in the public API, and if so, what must I avoid? Or is it inherently incompatible to mix C++11 and C++14 within the final software project?

It's a cross-platform library, BTW, so I'll need to build it on Linux, OSX, and Windows.

Comment: You can probably make it work as long as your clients use the same compiler versions even when they don't use the C++14 features. If they use a different version of compiler, it certainly won't work when using Visual Studio.

Comment: What is your exact compiler?  What compilers will consume it?

Comment: Clang on OSX; either Clang or gcc on Linux; MSVS on Windows. For the sake of argument, let's assume that the library and the app will both use the same compiler and same version, so my question boils down to whether I can use -std=c++14 for the library and -std=c++11 in the app, and what specific things I need to keep in mind for the public APIs to make it work.

Comment: I said exact.  The reason why I'm asking is that the C++ standard *does not specify anything about dynamic linking*, or cross-compiler linking, or anything like that.  Two programs compiled with the exact same version of gcc can fail to work when statically linked, let alone dynamically, based off compile-time flags (not `-std=c++14` specifically).  They can also work fine together.  So to solve your problem, you need to be talking about particular compilers and versions and libraries used, not the language as a whole.

Comment: You need to avoid putting `C++14` features in your headers. `ABI` is compiler dependant, `GCC v5.x` has an `ABI` *compatibility* switch with previous versions so compile with flag: `-D _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` if previous compiler versions are linking against it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: I can't be exact because I don't necessarily know which compilers the apps will use. That's why I'm asking what are the reasonable rules that will assure compatibility.

Comment: @Galik that has nothing to do with C++11 vs C++14 differences, and that ABI switch is orthogonal to the C++ language standard being used (you can use the new ABI with `-std=c++98`, or the old ABI with `-std=c++11`, or any other combination).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well I am answering two points. The clients expect `C++11` so I am suggesting avoiding `C++14` features *in the headers*. Of course they are fine in the binaries.

Answer (score 14):

> If I'm building a library where I assume that some "clients" of the library may only be using C++11, can I compile the library itself using C++14 for its internals?

Yes, in general that should be possible.

I do exactly that for GCC's implementation of the Filesystem TS. The `<experimental/filesystem>` header is written in pure C++11 and can be included by C++11 clients, but the implementation in `libstdc++fs.a` is written in C++14.

> Are there API/ABI/link compatibility issues versus C++11?

There are no changes between C++11 and C++14 that *require* implementations to break their link-time compatibility. That doesn't mean implementations *won't* break it, but they aren't required to.

For GCC I believe C++11 and C++14 are entirely API and ABI compatible, except for the `constexpr` and sized-deallocation issues mentioned below.

> Is it safe to implement and build the library with C++14 as long as I avoid certain new features in the public API, and if so, what must I avoid?

It depends on your compiler, but in theory it's possible.

Obviously avoid any C++14 language features that aren't valid in C++11 (such as function return type deduction, or generic lambdas with `auto` parameters, or variable templates) and any C++14 library entities, like `std::make_unique`, `std::integer_sequence, or`std::shared_timed_mutex`.

A list of nearly all the changes in C++14 can be found in [SD-6](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations#recs.cpp14).

One thing to watch out for is that the meaning of a non-static `constexpr` member function changed between C++11 and C++14. In C++11 this member function is `const`:

```
struct X {
  constexpr int foo();
};
```

In C++14 it is non-const. To be compatible with both C++11 and C++14 you should explicitly qualify it as `const`:

```
struct X {
  constexpr int foo() const;
};
```

That means the same thing in both C++11 and C++14.

Another caveat is that in C++11 and C++14 this operator means something different:

```
void operator delete(void*, std::size_t);
```

If C++11 client code defines that function then your library compiled in C++14 *could* end up calling it instead of the usual `operator delete(void*)` and that would presumably do the wrong thing. This is *probably* very uncommon and not a problem in real code, but it's possible. G++ and Clang allow you to compile C++14 code with `-fno-sized-deallocation` to disable the new feature, so that your C++14 library code would never call that version of `operator delete`.